# TeXworks: Can you set a default preamble when opening a new document?

Tags: texworks

Is there any way to set a default preamble in TeXworks? So, when I open the program for a new document, can I set it to automatically have something written there; mainly I'm thinking of the pre-amble but since I currently almost exclusively use TeXworks for university coursework, so I'd maybe put in a bit of other text too. Anyway, is this possible / easy to do?

Comment: You can create a template and use `Open from template`.

Answer (score 2):

Under your user texworks folder you'll find a `templates` folder. Create a `.tex` document with whatever content you want and save it there.

every time you want tu create a new document based in this template, open TeXworks and use File menu option `Open from template`. Your saved template will be there. Work with it and save your new document in your documents folder.

With MikTeX TeXworks (windows 10), I've found templates folder in `Users/<user name>/AppData/Local/MikTeX/2.9/TeXworks/0.4/templates`

With my local TeXwors (windows 10), template's folder is under `Users/<user name>/TeXworks/templates`